# Setting boolean field in before_create stops creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So this may have been a mistake.

In my model, on my `orders` table, I have a field named `active`. Its a boolean value and defaults to true. In a `before_create` on orders, I'm doing some logic that will set `active` to false if XYZ occurs.

When XYZ happens though, it seems to stop the record from being saved all together (without providing me any real errors), rather than just the field being set as false.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `active = false` at the end of your `before_create` filter, the filter will return `false` and halt the filter execution chain, cause the save not to complete.

If this is the case in your code, just return `true` at the end of your `before_create` and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm talking about setting self.active to false - is that different?

Comment: @Elliot Nope, that still returns `false`.

Comment: I dont understand why - if I have active defined as a field in my model, why should it halt the execution chain if I define it as false?

Comment: It's not the setting of the field that halts, it's the fact that it is the last value in the before_create method.

Comment: Elliot, 1. any method in ruby returns the last expression executed with an implicit return.  If the last expression you execute is "self.active = false", then false will be the value returned. 2. Any validation or callback (before_create, before_update, etc.) that returns false will halt the validation and it wont save.

Comment: You can see this easily in the rails console:
just set `Order.first.active = false` and have a look at the return value, it will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I have to insert 1==1 or true at the end of every before_create callback. Looks like something weird in callback definition.